# More aggressive regex for string with only 8 digits after underscore

Tags: regex, string

I currently have `\d{8}` as a regex pattern for detecting when a string contains `_12345678` where the digits can be any digit so long as there are eight digits and they follow a single underscore. This works fine for strings like `tysons_meats_12345678`, but doesn't work for strings like `geralds_meats_12345678_1234_12345678` as it gives a false positive.

I need a more aggressive regex pattern that ONLY true if the string is like `any_char3cter!_12345678` and is NOT true is there is multiple underscores followed by 8 digits like this `any_char3cter!_12345678_123_12345678`.

I have scoured Stack Overflow and spent 3+ hours looking through regex tutorials online to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: How about a simple negation rule: `not followed by _` =  `_\d{8}(?!_)`

Comment: Too little information and test cases to provide a good solution. @redneb's regex seems to work, but we don't know the specifics of your data enough to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
\D+_\d{8}\b
```

The `\b` ensures that we only match at word boundaries, and `\D` means that the character before the `_` is not a digit.

Comment: `\D+_\d{8}\b` Add the `+` after your `\D` and I can give you the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikÁsland I added it, in case you want to match with the entire word.

Comment: Thanks, bud! Appreciate the help!